# Blocking Port 8080 from direct IP access but allow access via domain (Virtualhost Config)

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, .htaccess, virtualhost, rewrite

I want to access web server from http://subdomain2.domain.com from URL but not from direct IP (http://1.1.1.1:8080). For instance, below is my virtualhost config file **(site2.conf)** in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` but section `<VirtualHost *:8080> ... </VirtualHost>` doesn't seem to have any affect.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain2.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain2.domain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
    Keepalive On

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/stream" ws://localhost:8080/ retry=0 timeout=5
    ProxyPass "/" http://localhost:8080/ retry=0 timeout=5
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName 1.1.1.1:8080
        ServerAlias  2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334:8080
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
        <Location />
            Require all denied
        </Location>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For http://subdomain1.domain.com, I have already implemented this successfully in **(000-default.conf)** in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and its working fine after adding section `<VirtualHost *:80> ... </VirtualHost>`. Below is the code for reference:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain1.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.subdomain1.domain.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 1.1.1.1
        ServerAlias  2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Location />
            Require all denied
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are *reverse proxying* to `localhost:8080`, there is probably some application server other than Apache listening on port `8080`. You cannot control that other software by adding VirtualHost configurations to Apache. Instead, change the settings of that software and make it only listen on local loopback (`localhost`) instead of every interface.

---

As it turns out the other server is Gotify, we can consult its [configuration documentation](https://gotify.net/docs/config).

> gotify/server looks in the following paths for config files
>
> `./config.yml`
> `/etc/gotify/config.yml`

> ```
> server:
>   keepaliveperiodseconds: 0 # ...
>   listenaddr: "" # the address to bind on, leave empty to bind on all addresses
>   port: 80 # the port for the http server
> ```

In this `config.yml`, change the parameter `server.listenaddr` to `127.0.0.1` as it defaults to listening on all addresses.

Comment: Yeah, app name is Gotify and i can change its port from 8080 to 9000 (or another). However, i am not sure what you mean by making it listen to loopback only. You mean i should use localhost:80 instead of *:80?

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover Gotify's configuration.

Comment: Changing  listenaddr: "" to  listenaddr: localhost in gotify actually results in opening content of subdomain1.domain.com (apache) when subdomain2.domain.com (gotify) is opened.

Comment: Um... WTF? That doesn't make much sense, or some crucial information on your setup is missing.

Comment: Maybe Gotify do not uses Apache server natively, so it might not be possible. I will do some further research. Maybe i need to chanhe gotify port from 8080 to some other

Comment: Gotify has nothing to do with Apache. You are simply putting the Apache as a reverse proxy in front of Gotify. It could as well be Nginx or something else.

Comment: I changed from port 8080 to 9000. Now it only opens from subdomain2.domain.com and do not open when public IP with 9000 port is accessed e-g 1.1.1.1:9000

I have not changed anything, except port. Also removed <VirtualHost *:8080> section